# StackOverflowError In Finding No of Ways

Tags: java, stack-overflow, combinations

Hi i am trying to write a Java code for the problem statement :

Find no of ways of distributing n coins to m members where one of them is captain(distributor). Each member can take 1 coin at a time and pass it to other members including captain. The captain cant  have the first coin. However, when there is just one coin left the the coin should be given to Captain. How many ways this is possible ?

I tied this. But getting `StackOverflowError`. Please Help.

Here i am making starting call as solve(1,n)

```
private static int solve(int r, int n)
    {
        int count = 0;
        if(n==2 && r!=1)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if(n==2 && r==1)
        {
            return 2;
        }
        for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)
        {
            if(r!=i)
            count += solve(i,--n);  
        }
            return count;
    }
```

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:50)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:62)
    at NoPrey.solve(NoPrey.java:
```

Comment: Guess that's your homework and you want to get it done while you spend time on facebook/twitter.

Comment: `for(int i=1;i<=m;i++)` what is m in your method? What is the value of r and n for which you are getting the error?

Comment: @Balwinder Thats not my homework sir, I was into learning java, and facing some issues..@YoungHobbit m is no. of members

Comment: @YoungHobbit m is no. of members that is global.

Comment: What are the values of m, n, and r for which you are getting exception

Comment: @a.......n For starters, it will be helpful if you use meaningful variable names instead of r,m and n. Also, share your stack trace

Comment: Any Values. Suppose m=3 n=4 and r is just for iterating i have called solve with solve(1, n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is just to help you understand the error.**

This is happening because value of n is going negative. Just put and `System.out.println(r + "\t\t" + n);` at the start of the method and run it again. `n=4` `m=3` and initial value of `r=1`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
  solve(1, 4);
}

private static int solve(int r, int n) {
  System.out.println(r + "\t\t" + n);
  // rest of the code same.
```

Output before error:
`1      4
2       3
1       2
3       1
1       0
2       -1
1       -2
2       -3
1       -4
2       -5
1       -6
2       -7
1       -8`

Comment: Solved it. Thanks a ton :)